# Действительно ли Qt не использует исключений?

Tags: c++, qt, исключения

Я имею в виду - не использует совсем? Ну вот прям *вообще-вообще*?

Это возможно?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на enSo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548951/why-doesnt-qt-use-exception-handling

Answer (score 1):

Все там используется и исключения в том числе.

> По историческим причинам, в основном. Поддержка исключения в
>   компиляторах заняла довольно много времени, чтобы созреть. Citation
>   Nokia Голос Тобиаса:
>
> "Когда Qt был запущен, исключения не были доступны для всех
>   компиляторов, которые должны были поддерживаться Qt. Сегодня мы
>   пытаемся сохранить API-интерфейсы согласованными, поэтому модули,
>   которые имеют историю отсутствия исключений, как правило, не получат
>   новый код с использованием исключений. **Вы заметите, что исключения
>   используются в некоторых новых модулях Qt.**
>
> tobias.hunger  MODERATORS 8 years ago When Qt was started exceptions
>   were not available for all the compilers that needed to be supported
>   by Qt. Today we are trying to keep the APIs consistent, so modules
>   that have a history of not using exceptions will generally not get new
>   code using exceptions added.
>
> **You will notice exceptions are used in some of the new modules of Qt.**

https://forum.qt.io/topic/1132/why-does-qt-use-so-few-exceptions

Восемь лет назад еще на форуме ответили разработчики, что в новых модулях Qt используются исключения. С тех пор количество исключений только увеличилось.

Не надо искать в С++ мифических несогласованностей, ужасов, глюков, костылей и прочих страстей. Их там нет. Есть миллионы успешных проектов на С++. Есть миллионы разработчиков, работающих на С++ и своей ежедневной работой проверяющих трансляторы. Есть миллиарды строк работающего кода на С++. И есть недобросовестные конкуренты, которые пытаются мазать дегтем чужие решения.

UPD1:

Кстати, ответ на этот вопрос я нашел просто задав в Гугле вопрос "Qt не использует исключений?". Вывалилось куча обсуждений на форумах и все они примерно десятилетней давности. Видно с тех пор народ успокоился и принял исключения в Qt как данность.

UPD2:

Стерто злым модером.

UPD3:

> Эх, а я уже было обрадовался, что можно не заниматься выворачиванием
>   мозга наизнанку для написания exception-safety кода...

Если делать все как надо, то exception-safety код получается сам собой. А если делать все как **НЕ** надо, то ошибки вылезут задолго до выбрасывания первого исключения.

Да и вообще, никто не стал бы заморачиваться, выдумывать концепцию исключений, потом писать поддержку исключений в трансляторах, если бы другие методы проверки ошибок (в частности, проверка кода возврата) удовлетворяли бы индустрию. Так что исключения must be. Исключения это хорошо, исключения это правильно, исключения это лучшее на сегодняшний момент решение.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но совершенно непонятно, при чем тут последний абзац про ужасы и деготь.

Comment: @Kromster Можете считать это моим старческим брюзжанием.

Comment: Эх, а я уже было обрадовался, что можно не заниматься выворачиванием мозга наизнанку для написания *exception-safety* кода...

Answer (score -1):

Не использует по ряду причин. Совсем-совсем. Это тянется ещё с тех времён, когда исключения кушали память и размер исполняемого файла.

Comment: И как решаются отказы всяких там выделений памяти, кривых кастований и тому подобные вещи?

Comment: классически - возвращаем 0/nullptr. Например, так делает qobject_cast

Comment: Решаются при помощи функции qWarning